# Macbook connecting to hotspot - slow wi-fi after wake from sleep

Tags: wifi, tethering

I have a macbook pro 15" 2017. I use an Android hotspot to connect to internet.

Every night I put my Mac to sleep and turn off the hotspot. When I come back in the morning I turn the Android hotspot on and wake up my Mac. The wi-fi is slow and sometimes drops. Pinging google.com shows results from 30ms to 2000ms.

If I restart my Mac everything works normally – ping is around 30. What can I do so that I wouldn't have to restart my Mac every day?

( Also windows device on the same network works perfectly well )

Comment: I have exact same problem. What's even weirder, while laptop is connected to my android samsung note 10 plus, even the phone can't ping google.com while laptop ping is through the roof. I check network activity and nothing is downloading!

The moment I disconnect the wifi, the phone is able to ping google.com very very fast. Connect back to wifi hotspot, the phone again stops pinging google and laptop ping is again through the roof!
Shutting down solved the problem!

Answer (score 2):

This is technically not a fix but I think toggling wifi off and on solves the issue, without having to restart your mac. I have the same issue on my 2018 mac mini, and the only way I found to avoid this issue is to not put it to sleep.

Comment: That didn't work for me. But shutting down then starting the laptop worked like a charm.